# How add VueJS event listenner on a component in the mounted section

Tags: javascript, vue.js, addeventlistener

I important a componant and I want to attach an event listenner to the button element which has the class `qkb-bubble-btn`.

I understand the fact I should put this in the `mounted` section but I get the following error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getElementsByClassName')
```

Here is how I try to add the listenner :

```
<script>
import {VueBotUI} from 'vue-bot-ui'
import {subscribeUser} from "../helpers/subscriptionHandler";
//import {getAlerte} from "../helpers/alerteHandler";

export default {
//...
  mounted() {
    this.document.getElementsByClassName('qkb-bubble-btn ')[0].addEventListener('click', this.onBubbleClick);
  },
  beforeDestroy () {
    navigator.serviceWorker.removeEventListener('message', event => {
      this.printPush(event);
    });
    this.document.getElementsByClassName('qkb-bubble-btn ')[0].removeEventListener('click', this.onBubbleClick);
  },
  methods: {
    onBubbleClick(){
      console.log("click bubble")
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

How should I add the click event listenner to the `qkb-bubble-btn` element ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add an event listener yourself,

you just use `@` and the name of your event on the button :

```
<my-button @click="myClickMethod"/>
```

You only use addEventListener if the element is outside of vue app, but if it's inside the app, then better use vue way of doing it

And if the button is inside another component you will need to use $emit :

```
<my-button @click="$emit('click', $event)"/>
```

Comment: But I can't modify the code of the component which bring this button, that's why I need to add it manually

Comment: Even if it's a third party component it should have events you could listen to, perhaps it emit back the click event, and perhaps they used v-bind="$attrs" in that case your @click will apply to the button inside, it vastly depends on the third party component and what they provide. If they don't provide anything you can hook into, then yes you will have no other choice than addEventListener, but mounted might be too soon, you will need to wait for that element to exist in the dom

Answer (score 0):

Even if @lk77 is right, I could fix my issue by removing the keyword `this` in front of `this.document...`